# Transfer txt file from oracle data base server to local machine using PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a txt file in a particular location in Oracle database server. I need to transfer that txt file into my local machine using PL/SQL. Is there possibility to do that task.

[Sample txt file located in database server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZFTo.jpg)

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/ftp-from-plsql

Comment: "Copying files" really isn't a task that a **database** should manage. Why don't you just copy it to your computer using your operating system capabilities?

Comment: Use sqlplus to grab the file from the Oracle server directory (UTL_FILE package, for instance) and spool its contents to your client machine, saving results in a local file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a routine to load a file into the database (if needed), and to subsequently retrieve via OWA, which would then expose using MOD_PLSQL, DBMS_EPG or similar mechanism to allow making a http call to your database

```
create table demo
( id int primary key,
theBlob blob
)
/

create or replace directory my_files as 'where your file is located';

declare
  l_blob blob;
  l_bfile bfile;
begin
  insert into demo values ( 1, empty_blob() )
  returning theBlob into l_blob;

  l_bfile := bfilename( 'MY_FILES', 'aria.fname' );
  dbms_lob.fileopen( l_bfile );

  dbms_lob.loadfromfile( l_blob, l_bfile,
  dbms_lob.getlength( l_bfile ) );

  dbms_lob.fileclose( l_bfile );
end;
/ 


create or replace package file_get
as
  procedure fname( p_id in demo.id%type );
end;
/

create or replace package body file_get
as

procedure fname( p_id in demo.id%type )
is
  l_lob blob;
  l_amt number default 30;
  l_off number default 1;
  l_raw raw(4096);
begin
  select theBlob into l_lob
  from demo
  where id = p_id;

  -- make sure to change this for your type!
  owa_util.mime_header( 'image/pdf' );

  begin
  loop
    dbms_lob.read( l_lob, l_amt, l_off, l_raw );

    -- it is vital to use htp.PRN to avoid
    -- spurious line feeds getting added to your
    -- document
    htp.prn( utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2( l_raw ) );
    l_off := l_off+l_amt;
    l_amt := 4096;
  end loop;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    NULL;
end;

end;

end;
/
```